# "The bless tool was unable to set the current boot disk" error in bootcamp macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, parallels-desktop

**Problem:**

I can no longer boot Boot Camp partition (BCP) running Windows 10 Pro 1703. I am also unable to start Parallels 12.2.0 Virtual Machine based on the same BCP macOS side. Problem occurred suddenly without warning. I cannot isolate any action from user side that could have led to this situation. I did *not* try to resize partition. I would like to boot from internal BCP as I was able to a few hours ago if possible. I do have a backup saved disc image (WinClone 6) from a few weeks back and a backup I made after the issue began. I would like to avoid a solution where I have to clone BCP to external SSD and transfer it back to notebook.

**Mac Notebook Specs:**

[image]

**`diskutil list` Output:**

[image]

**`diskutil cs list` Output:**

[image]

**Disk Utility Report:**

[image]

[image]

**Virtual Machine Output:**
[image]

- BCP is Not Visible at Startup (was few hours back)
- BCP is Visible in Startup Disk in Preferences without
  Paragon NTFS for Mac 15.0.828 installed (but cannot restart from BCP disk)
- BCP is Not Visible in Startup Disk in Preferences with
  Paragon NTFS for Mac 15.0.828 installed (but cannot restart from BCP disk using NTFS for Mac)
- BCP is mountable/visible on Desktop
- Disk Utility not allowing me to verify/repair disk (grayed out/dimmed selection for applying First Aid to BCP)

[image]

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

- HOLD ALT at Restart (x3) -> Only macOS partition visible
- CMD+R (Recovery Mode) + Verify + BCP select restart -> "The bless tool was unable to set the
  current boot disk"

[image]
[image]
[image]

- ALT+CMD+R+P (Reset NVRAM) -> No resolution
- Verify disk using Paragon NTFS for Mac 15.0.828 -> Success:

[image]

- Repair disk using Paragon NTFS for Mac 15.0.828 -> Success:

[image]

- ALT+CMD+R+P (Reset NVRAM) -> No resolution:

[image]

- Google
- Made post on stack exchange
- Made appt for Genius Bar

**07/05/17 Update:**

**`diskutil verifyDisk disk0`**:

```
Started partition map verification on disk0
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Checking the partition map size
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition's size
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content
Checking all HFS data partition loader spaces
Checking booter partitions
Checking booter partition disk0s3
Verifying file system
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking extents overflow file
Checking catalog file
Checking multi-linked files
Checking catalog hierarchy
Checking extended attributes file
Checking volume bitmap
Checking volume information
The volume Recovery HD appears to be OK
File system check exit code is 0
Checking Core Storage Physical Volume partitions
Verifying storage system
Checking volume
disk0s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk0s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Logical Volume Group CAF0EF87-18B3-429E-B956-071C41913E1E on 1 device
disk0s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
Logical Volume Group has a 24 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Load and verify Checkpoint Payload
Load and verify Transaction Segment
Incorporate 0 newer non-checkpoint transactions
Load and verify Virtual Address Table
Load and verify Segment Usage Table
Load and verify Metadata Superblock
Load and verify Logical Volumes B-Trees
Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volume
Load and verify ABA4E795-98B7-41CB-B45B-2A85180C8204
Load and verify C37D4F73-4CF7-4E22-BD12-732A22ECD7EA
Load and verify Freespace Summary
Load and verify Block Accounting
Load and verify Live Virtual Addresses
Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
Load and verify Segment Cleaning
The volume CAF0EF87-18B3-429E-B956-071C41913E1E appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
The partition map appears to be OK
Finished partition map verification on disk0
```

**`sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`:**

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 1607 installed using BootCamp Assistant. I have to believe partition made was Master Boot Record (MBR) not GUI Partition Table (GPT) since I always intended to boot Win10 from BCP. I upgraded to 1703 Creators Update at the recommendation of Windows Technical Support to resolve problem with installing compatibility .NET Frameworks 3.5 (2.0 and 3.0 included) but this was several weeks ago. No start up problems until yesterday. Boot times are usually fast.

Comment: I posted output to diskutil verify disk0. I don't see any info on disk0s4 and disk0s5?

Comment: *Verify disk0* seems ok. You should be able to get the install method by entering `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`. If you get one entry it's probably GPT. If you get four entries it's probably MBR. On a MBP 2016 usually (often?) the GPT method is used. Check some answers of [David](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/107222/david-anderson). He is the specialist for BC related stuff here, wasn't seen for 8 months though. Hint: please post text output (like the result of *verifyDisk*) as formatted text. Then it's much easier to copy and paste stuff like UUIDs etc.

Comment: @klanomath There are indeed four entries but three of them are "unused"? I've added inline code formatted text where appropriate. Also since I don't know if this is a macOS or Windows hiccup I tried using windows tools to repair BCP: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288931/advanced-troubleshooting-tips-for-macos-sierra-boot-camp-partition-bcp

Comment: Unused entries are no entries ;-). Consequently it's a GPT install... [How do I repartition my Mac to get rid of my dual boot setup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192437/93229) > Update 1 > second text box *(sudo fdisk /dev/disk2)* shows a typical MBR with a Boot Camp partition installed via MBR method.

Comment: "I would like to avoid a solution where I have to clone BCP to external SSD and transfer it back to notebook." I hope someone else is able to provide such a solution, but given the amount of time you've clearly already lost on troubleshooting, a backup + reformat seems like it would be the most efficient option.

Comment: @klanomath I understand this is a GPT install on an EFI partition. But I've been able to successfully boot into Windows for several months. So why do you think I can't boot the disk?

Comment: @Quesop I assume that a Windows update is the culprit or some Parallels + Windows + new Win update interaction.

Comment: @klanomath This is why I wanted to perform a system restore. But I run into a "you must specify which windows installation to restore" error warning. 7th screenshot here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288931/advanced-troubleshooting-tips-for-macos-sierra-boot-camp-partition-bcp

Comment: @Quesop You should probably use the [Anniversary Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018812/new-install-of-windows-10-creators-update-on-mac-with-boot-camp)

Comment: I needed the Creators Windows to run an application windows side. There was no helping the upgrade. I just realized I didn't make a block based backup of the BCP in winclone. I may not be able to recover from the backups after all. Not good. Do you know how to format an external MS-DOS (FAT) fs drive from 512 bytes per sector to 4096 (4k) bytes per sector? what I want is to boot backups from samsung t3 external ssd before attempting to restore internal BCP -> http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3291132/format-external-hard-drive-advance-format.html#lastAnswer

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I'm attempting your preferred option. Can you answer this question? -> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/289159/how-to-format-external-ssd-to-boot-boot-camp-partition-bcp-backups-from-extern

Comment: @Quesop If it was me, I wouldn't even be cloning. Copy all important files to external drive, reinstall Windows / Bootcamp, copy back. Yes it's a pain; I suspect it will save time in the long run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve macOS Sierra error about the bless tool by using the pictured setting on WinClone 6.0.3. I did not restore from winclone backup but rather just made my BCP bootable as an EFI instead of legacy BIOS drive. For some reason macOS started to view BCP as an unbootable legacy BIOS drive. My guess is installing Paragon suite of tools like NTFS, Hard Disk Manager, and ExtFS for Mac had this sudden and unintended result during the runtime environment.

[image]

To prevent BSOD sysprep appears to be necessary when restoring WinClone backups on external drives.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem restoring a Macbook Pro from 2009 with Yosemite. After many tries. I found you that it relates to making one partision formatting the disk.

I created a bootable disk from instructions:https://pureinfotech.com/create-macos-bootable-usb-windows/

I downloaded an image from : https://allmacworld.com/mac-os-x-yosemite-10-10-3-free-download/

I started the MAc over USB (press down option key on MAC. Went to utilities and formatted the SSD with one partition, **explicitely selecting it!**

Last step is to follow the insturctions to install the OS

Answer (score 0):

W10 is automatically supposed to bring up Windows Recovery after three or more boot failures. If you have only the internal disk without any other storage, Recovery will try to fix the BCP. You can use bootrec or Startup Repair to check if W10 Recovery can correct the issue with BCP.

The July 4th backup is the most reasonable one to test for restore.

I downloaded an image from : https://filesvilla.com/mac-os-x-yosemite-10-10-5-for-mac-dmg-free-download/

I started the MAc over USB (press down option key on MAC. Went to utilities and formatted the SSD with one partition, explicitely selecting it!

Last step is to follow the insturctions to install the OS